# xlxs file response not correct. It returning garbage symbols on response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
def daily_report_summery(request):
    body = request.body
    data = json.loads(body)
    date = data['date']
    generate_summary_report_xl(date)
    with open('./Daily_Report.xlsx', "rb") as file:
      response = HttpResponse(file.read(),content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
      response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=Daily_Report.xlsx'
    return response
```

I am getting this responce:
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6M2R.png)

I want to send Daily_Report.xlsx file from backend.

Comment: Take a look at `FileResponse` instead of HttpResponse. `response = FileResponse(open(filename, 'rb'), as_attachment=True)`

Comment: `response = FileResponse(open('Daily_Report.xlsx', 'rb'), as_attachment=True)
        return response` I used this but not working showing same result

Comment: This problem is solved. I was missing `responseType: 'blob'` in axios call